# Why can't I find my uploaded file on disk?

Tags: 7, files

I have a form with a file upload widget:

```
$form['myFile'] = array(
    '#tree' => false,
    '#type' => 'file',
    '#title' => t('Choose a file')
);
```

In the form validation handler, I upload the file and validate it with:

```
$validators = array(
    "file_validate_extensions" => array(variable_get("allowed_extensions")),
    "file_validate_size" => array(variable_get("max_image_size"))
);
$file = file_save_upload('myFile', $validators);
$form_state['file_storage']['myFile'] = $file;
```

Then, in the submit handler, I save the file using:

```
$file = $form_state['file_storage']['myFile'];
file_save($file);
```

This seems to work fine as I can find an entry for the file in the `file_managed` table:

```
+-----+-----+--------------+-----------------------------+------------+----------+--------+------------+
| fid | uid | filename     | uri                         | filemime   | filesize | status | timestamp  |
+-----+-----+--------------+-----------------------------+------------+----------+--------+------------+
|  49 |   1 | download.jpg | temporary://download.jpg    | image/jpeg |     5410 |      0 | 1350312114 |
+-----+-----+--------------+-----------------------------+------------+----------+--------+------------+
```

The problem is that I can't find the file anywhere on disk:

```
$ su -
Password:
# updatedb
# locate download.jpg
/home/me/Pictures/download.jpg
```

As you can see, the only `download.jpg` found is the one in my pictures folder which I passed into the form. I can't find anything *on the server* (in `/var/www/`). So where is the file? Is it a BLOB in the drupal database? Has it simply not been uploaded properly? If so, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're just missing the third parameter for `file_save_upload()`:

> $destination: A string containing the URI $source should be copied to. This must be a stream wrapper URI. If this value is omitted, Drupal's temporary files scheme will be used ("temporary://").

The uri in your table is `temporary://download.jpg` which seems to support that.

To save your file in the public file system you just need to pass that parameter in:

```
$destination = 'public://some/folder/';
$file = file_save_upload('myFile', $validators, $destination);
```

Comment: Right you are. For the record, I used `public://images`, but I had to create the folder myself and change the user for it to work: `cd /var/www/drupal/sites/default/files/; mkdir images; chown apache images`